# Performing a PHP redirect for an API during a jquery ajax get returning 302

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I'm calling a php page through `jQuery ajax` which connects to an API, gets the request token, performs a header redirect back to the same page, than upon return it returns a json encoded string. However, its returning a 302 error.

My question is, how do I implement this to work properly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: Start by providing lots of additional information. It may seem obvious to you, but we start with zero knowledge of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide a basic example with 2 files.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var param = 'name=YourName';
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "phpcallback.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: param,
        dataType: "json"
    });     
    request.done(function(response) {       
        $("#Mydiv").html(response); 
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Mydiv">
Click to get json response from server
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

phpcallback.php

```
<?php
  $Name = $_POST['name'];
  $Arr = array();
  $cn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("mydb", $cn);
  $Query = mysql_query("select * from mytable where name = '$Name'",$cn);
  $Row = mysql_fetch_array($Query);     
  $Arr = array('Null');     
  $Arr = array($Row['Name'],$Row['Email'],$Row['Address'],$Row['Phone']);   
  echo json_encode($Arr);   
?>
```

This code should work provided you have your Database setup accordingly

Regards
Immanuel Paul